# shared_ptr aliasing constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, shared-ptr

Question about following `shared_ptr` constructor:

```
template< class Y >
shared_ptr( const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *ptr );
```

Am I correct that if `r` was created using user-provided deleter, then aliasing `shared_ptr` knows that. So if aliasing `shared_ptr` is last in the group and (when going out of scope) destructs resources originally managed by `r`, it will use that user-provided deleter?

Comment: Yes. This ctor creates a `shared_ptr` that shares ownership with `r`. That is, the user-provided deleter of `r` is used to destroy the pointer stored in `r`.

Comment: Sometimes it should be allowed to make comment with less than 15 characters, three in this case :)

Comment: @DanielFrey You mean, *No!* ? ;D

Comment: I was going to answer, but I feel bad about it... nothing interesting to say other than the *yes* already commented above. @DyP, you should provide an answer, if nothing else you were the first one to see/answer this!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

struct some_type
{
    int i;
};

void my_deleter(some_type* p)
{
std::cout << "my_deleter called!" << std::endl;
    delete p;
}

#include <memory>
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> pm;

    {
        // Note: better use make_shared
        auto x = new some_type;
        // create a shared_ptr that owns x and a deleter
        std::shared_ptr<some_type> r(x, &my_deleter);
        std::cout << r.use_count() << std::endl;

        // share ownership of x and the deleter with pm
        pm = std::shared_ptr<int>(r, &r->i);
        std::cout << r.use_count() << std::endl;

        // r gets destroyed
    }
    std::cout << pm.use_count() << std::endl;
    std::cout << "get_deleter == 0? " << std::boolalpha
              << (nullptr == std::get_deleter<decltype(&my_deleter)>(pm))
              << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
1
2
1
get_deleter == 0? false
my_deleter called!
```

N.B. I can't compile this example with a free function `my_deleter`, there's some casting error for the free `get_deleter` function (trying to cast from `void*` to a function pointer type with a `static_cast`).

---

Aliasing ctor:
[util.smartptr.shared.const]/13-14

> ```
> template<class Y> shared_ptr(const shared_ptr<Y>& r, T *p) noexcept;
> ```
>
> 13 *Effects:* Constructs a `shared_ptr` instance that stores `p` and *shares ownership* with `r`.
>
> 14 *Postconditions:* `get() == p && use_count() == r.use_count()`

Ctor with user-provided deleter:
[util.smartptr.shared.const]/9

> template shared_ptr(Y* p, D d);
>
> *Effects:* Constructs a `shared_ptr` object that *owns* the object `p` and the deleter `d`.

Dtor:
[util.smartptr.shared.dest]/1

> ~shared_ptr();
>
> 1 *Effects:*
>
> - If `*this` is *empty* or shares ownership with another `shared_ptr` instance (`use_count() > 1`), there are no side effects.
> - Otherwise, if `*this` *owns* an object `p` and a deleter `d`, `d(p)` is called.
> - Otherwise, `*this` *owns* a pointer `p`, and `delete p` is called.

Combining those (let's skip the assignment operators):

- The `shared_ptr` instance `r` *owns* both the object and the deleter.
- The aliasing ctor lets the new `shared_ptr` instance *share ownership* with `r` (i.e. for both, the object and the deleter).
- When the dtor of this new instance is called (or an assignment operator),

  - If `use_count > 1`, no effects.
  - Else, this instance *owns* the object which `r` pointed to *and* the deleter (if any) and will either use this deleter (if it exists) or `delete` on the object pointed to.

Comment: @user2052436, `shared_ptr` has no `get_deleter` member. `get_deleter` is a free function, and you need to provide a template argument list, e.g. `get_deleter<my_deleter>(aliased_shared_ptr)`, which will return non-null.  Instead of asking about the behaviour of code that won't even compile, why not try compiling it?

Comment: @user2052436 No. [util.smartptr.getdeleter]/1 "If `p` owns a deleter `d` of type *cv*-unqualified `D`, returns `&d`; otherwise returns `0`.

Comment: The `shared_ptr` constructors take the deleter by value, so when using a free function as a deleter the type that gets passed to the constructor as the deleter is a _pointer_ to function, so you need to use `get_deleter<void(*)(some_type*)>` to retrieve it. If you try to use `get_deleter<void(some_type*)>` you get the error you described

Comment: @JonathanWakely Thanks! Indeed I was missing a `&` or a `*`. The error I got confused me: "`static_cast` from `void *` to `void (*)(some_type *)` is not allowed"

Comment: Why `shared_ptr`'s aliasing constructor is `noexcept`? I thank a correct deleter should be construct in this constructor, and this action may be not `noexcept`.

Comment: @linux40 No, a deleter is not constructed in the aliasing ctor. This ctor *shares ownership* with an existing `shared_ptr`, and the deleter is part of this. The bookkeeping object of shared pointers which corresponds to the ownership concept contains the strong and weak ref counts as well as the deleter.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because a deleter is stored in the shared_ptr's counter (the 'pn' member `boost::detail::shared_count`) and aliasing actually shares the counter.