# accessing derived member variables via pointers to derived class

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

I try to understand the logic behind accessing members of a derived object. I have two pointers: If I change the variable in my derived class via a pointer to the derived class, I notice that I am not able to access the value of the variable via a inheritance type of pointer to the base class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class A
    {
    public:
        int x;
    };

class B : public A
    {
    public:
        int y;
    };

int main()
    {
    B* pB = new B;
    A* pA = new B;

    std::cout<<"Changing x via pB to 11"<<std::endl;
    pB->x=11;
    std::cout<<"This is x: " << pB->x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"What about this x: " << pA->x<<std::endl<<std::endl;

    std::cout<<"Changing x via pA to 42"<<std::endl;
    pA->x=42;
    std::cout<<"This is my new x: " << pB->x<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"and what about this x now: " << pA->x;

    delete pA;
    delete pB;
    }
```

Output:

> Changing x via pB to 11
>   This is x: 11
>   What about this x: 0
>
> Changing x via pA to 42
>   This is my new x: 11
>   and what about this x now: 42

I would like to know what has happens and why there are two different values for x. What also bothers me is that when I work, for example, with multiple lists: a master list with pointers to all my objects (say some animal class) and a secondary list--a sub-sample of the master list with pointers to some objects (say class reptile: public animal, public predator)--and it happens that I wish to modify the values of these members through the second list (bool is_currently_in_water), I cannot do this in a straightforward (and to me intuitive) way. I have to keep track of the master list and first find out which animal object is a reptile, in order to make the necessary changes through the master list.

Is polymorphism intended to be like this? This is perhaps a very basic question as I am a beginning to learn C++, and although I know how to overcome the problem my changing my code, I first trying to fully grasp what is going on as the above result was rather surprising.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know what has happens and why there are two different values for `x`.

The explanation is quite simple: you have two values of `x` because you have two separate objects of type `B`, referenced through two pointers `pA` and `pB`, which are completely independent of each other.

When you print `pB->x` you print `x` attached to the object that you have allocated first; when you print `pA-X`, you print `x` attached to the object that you have allocated second. These two objects do not share member variables, so their `x`s are independent of each other.

If you would like to see behavior when two pointers of different type refer to the same object, do this:

```
B* pB = new B;
A* pA = pB;
```

Now `pA` and `pB` are pointing to the same object, so any changes to `x` through one pointer would be "visible" through the other pointer. Of course, now that there is only one allocation, you need to remove `delete pA` (or `delete pB` if you prefer) to avoid double-deletion of the same object.

Comment: that's it! That's what I wanted! Many thanks.. How stupid of me! I didn't noticed my mistake and my program was going well, until suddenly I was querying the strange behavior! Since you intuitively knew what I was trying to do, I will give you the vote (although you answered second).... :-)

Comment: btw. how do I do that with shared_ptr? Getting strange error message here.

Comment: @user2856452 This is a very interesting question to which SO has a couple of good answers( [1](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19102034/335858) and [2](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27109379/335858)).

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 different values because you have 2 different objects:

```
B* pB = new B;
A* pA = new B;
```

The object `pA` points to has no relation whatsoever with the one `pB` points to. And, in the first

```
std::cout<<"What about this x: " << pA->x<<std::endl<<std::endl;
```

you are reading uninitialized data, which is undefined behaviour.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you! I wanted actually to make two pointers to the same object (but referring to different base classes) is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You trying to read x from two different object.

If you want to refer to you object with the parent pointer you need to define a parent pointer like the following

```
B* pB = new B;
A* pA = pB;
```

Now if you change x from pointer pA, it will be changed on pB too.